# Virtual foldersystem in MySql, with "templates"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to make a "virtual filesystem" in MySql (using asp.net as the web-application). It's not going to be very complex, probably maximum 2-3 subfolders "deep", with maybe up to 10 files in each folder. Each user will have their own folders and files after they log in. The admin(s) should be able to make "templates", and assign a template to new users. A template will have a few folders and files in it. And this is what I'm scratching my head on how to make. I think I'm at least close to design the tables, but I'm not sure. Here is the tables I've created so far:

```
Files
 ID
 Name
 ContentType
 FileDataSize
 FileData
 Parent_Folder_ID

Folders
 ID
 Name
 Parent_Folder_ID

Users
 ID
 Name
 Email
 Password

Templates
 ID
 Name

User_Templates
 User_ID
 Template_ID
```

Am i on the right track here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I would use [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) for the folder hierarchy. Adjacency lists will work but are painful due to the need for recursion. You appear to be missing an association table for linking users to folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty simple, and this will probably just work for your purposes.
The only problem you will run into, is that you will need several queries to determine the the full path for a leaf node.

The easiest way to solve this, is to actually store the full path in a separate column, such as:

folder1/folder2/node

Not as pretty, but certainly the absolute easiest to deal with.

Alternatively, you could use the preorder tree traversal algorithm, but this can be more complex, and while fetching sub-tree's is fast, updates may be incredibly slow.

Comment: You mean to add a "FullPath" column to the Folders table then?

Comment: Well yes.. but try it out? What queries you do need? Once you write the queries you will quickly find out what's missing and whats difficult